# Is there a way to drop a new file into an encrypted folder in OS X without mounting it?

Tags: mac, encryption, sparsebundle

What I'd like to do is have a encrypted bundle that I can throw my financial documents into. But I don't want it mounted all the time for security reasons, and it's a pain to click on it, type in the password, copy the stuff over, then unmount it. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Not without compromising the security. You can do it with a script, but it would save the password in clear text on the script